# Serialization and Des-Serialization of structure and text file

Tags: c, networking, serialization, openssl, deserialization

I am doing serialization of a structure in C but I am having a problem which I can figure it out:s The code is a bit long but I think it is ok to understand.

This is the top level structure I am trying to serialize:

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t protocol_version;
    ContentType signed_content_type;
    signedDATA signed_data;
}data1609Dot2SignData;
```

Contentype and signedDATA are other structures as defined bellow:

```
typedef enum
{
    UNSECURED,
    SIGNED,
    ENCRYPTED,
    CERTIFICATE_REQUEST,
    CERTIFICATE_RESPONSE,
    ANONYMOUS_CERTIFICATE_RESPONSE,
    CERTIFICATE_REQUEST_ERROR,  
    CRL_REQUEST,
    CRL,
    SIGNED_PARTIAL_PAYLOAD,
    SIGNED_EXTERNAL_PAYLOAD,
    SIGNED_WSA,
    CERTIFICATE_RESPONSE_ACKNOWLEDGMENT
}ContentType;

typedef struct
{
    ToBeSignedDATA unsigned_data;
    Signature signature;
}signedDATA;

typedef struct
{
    Psid psid;
    octet_string data;
}ToBeSignedDATA;

typedef uint32_t Psid;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t length;
    char* content;
} octet_string;

typedef struct
{
    PKAlgorithm algorithm;
    ECDSA_SIG* sig; 
}Signature;

typedef enum
{
    ECDSA_NISTP224_WITH_SHA224,
    ECDSA_NISTP256_WITH_SHA256,
    ECIES_NISTP256
}PKAlgorithm;
```

I created 2 functions one to serialize and another to deserialize:

```
    int serialize1609Dot2DATA(data1609Dot2SignData x,char** buffer)
    {
        //printf(" Serialize: (sig->r, sig->s): (%s,%s)\n", BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->r), BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->s));

// load of text file to buffer. //
        char* cert_buffer = 0;
        cert_buffer = NULL;
        int certificate_length = 0;
        FILE* f = fopen("ecdsa256.crt", "r");

        if(f)
        {
            fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
            certificate_length = ftell(f);
            fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
            cert_buffer = calloc(1, certificate_length);
            if(cert_buffer)
            {
                fread(cert_buffer, 1, certificate_length, f);           
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
    // end.

        uint32_t msg_data_len = x.signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length;    // size of data.
        char* sig_big_num_r;
        char* sig_big_num_s;

        int size_sig_r, size_sig_s = 0;
        sig_big_num_r = BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->r);
        sig_big_num_s = BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->s);

        size_sig_r = strlen(sig_big_num_r);
        size_sig_s = strlen(sig_big_num_s);

        int serialize_size = 0;
        serialize_size = certificate_length + sizeof(x.protocol_version) + sizeof(x.signed_content_type) + size_sig_r + size_sig_s + sizeof(x.signed_data.signature.algorithm) + sizeof(x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid) + msg_data_len + sizeof(uint32_t); 

        *buffer = 0;
        *buffer = calloc(1, sizeof(char)*serialize_size);

        if(*buffer)
        {
            size_t offset = 0;

            memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length, sizeof(uint32_t));     // size of the data field.
            offset += sizeof(uint32_t);

            memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.protocol_version, sizeof(x.protocol_version));    // protocol version
            offset += sizeof(x.protocol_version);

            memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_content_type, sizeof(x.signed_content_type)); // signed content type
            offset += sizeof(x.signed_content_type);

            strcpy(*buffer+offset, sig_big_num_r);                                        //    Sig r
            offset += size_sig_r;           

            strcpy(*buffer+offset, sig_big_num_s);                                        // Sig s
            offset += size_sig_s;

            memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_data.signature.algorithm, sizeof(x.signed_data.signature.algorithm));  // algorithm
            offset += sizeof(x.signed_data.signature.algorithm);

            memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid, sizeof(x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid)); // PSID
            offset += sizeof(x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid);

            memcpy(*buffer+offset, cert_buffer, certificate_length); // certificate buffer(buffer of the text file) is set here.

            offset += certificate_length;

            memcpy(*buffer+offset, x.signed_data.unsigned_data.data.content, x.signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length);      // data.        
            offset += msg_data_len; 

        }
        OPENSSL_free(sig_big_num_r);
        OPENSSL_free(sig_big_num_s);
        return serialize_size;
    }
```

and:

```
data1609Dot2SignData* deserialize1609Dot2DATA(char* serialdata)
{
data1609Dot2SignData* y = 0;

y = malloc(sizeof(data1609Dot2SignData)); 

if(y)
{
    size_t offset = 0;
    memcpy(&y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(uint32_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint32_t);

    uint32_t data_len = y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length;
//  printf("DATA LEN in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", data_len);

    memcpy(&y->protocol_version, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->protocol_version));
    offset += sizeof(y->protocol_version);

    //printf("Protocol_version in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->protocol_version);

    memcpy(&y->signed_content_type, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->signed_content_type));
    offset += sizeof(y->signed_content_type);

//  printf("Signed content type in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->signed_content_type);

    //y->signed_data.signature.sig->r = malloc(32);
    char* tmp_sig_r = calloc(1, 64);
    char* tmp_sig_s = calloc(1, 64);
    ECDSA_SIG* sig = calloc(1, 128);
    BIGNUM* big_r = calloc(1, 64);
    BIGNUM* big_s = calloc(1, 64);

    memcpy(tmp_sig_r, (serialdata + offset), 64);
    offset += 64; //
    BN_hex2bn(&big_r, tmp_sig_r);
//  y->signed_data.signature.sig->r= big_r;
//  printf("SIZE R: %d\n", r);
    sig->r = big_r;

    memcpy(tmp_sig_s, (serialdata + offset), 64);
    offset += 64;
    BN_hex2bn(&big_s, tmp_sig_s);
//  printf("SIZE S: %d\n", s);
    sig->s = big_s;

    y->signed_data.signature.sig = sig;

//  printf(" Deserialize: (sig->r, sig->s): (%s,%s)\n",tmp_sig_r ,tmp_sig_s);

    memcpy(&y->signed_data.signature.algorithm, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->signed_data.signature.algorithm));
    offset += sizeof(y->signed_data.signature.algorithm);

//  printf("Algorithm in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->signed_data.signature.algorithm);

    memcpy(&y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid));
    offset += sizeof(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid);

//  printf("PSID in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid);

    char* certificate_buffer = calloc(1, 956);
    memcpy(certificate_buffer, (serialdata + offset), 956);
    offset += 956;

// write the buffer with the data back to a text file:
        size_t size_cert = 956; 


    FILE* out = fopen("output.crt", "w");
    fwrite(certificate_buffer, 1, size_cert, out);

    y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.content = malloc(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length);
    memcpy(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.content, (serialdata + offset), y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length);  // msg data.
    offset += y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length;

    fclose(out);

    free(certificate_buffer);

    free(tmp_sig_r);
    free(tmp_sig_s);
}
return y;
}
```

I'm having problems when I had the serialization and de-serialization of the file I am trying to serialize. If I take it out everything works ok, otherwise I get bad de-serialized values:s
In the Des-serialization I assigning the size of the buffer to 956, because I know this size will always be fixed and the file will have always the same amount of data and it is always the same file.

I have been over hours looking over this and I can't find out the mistake:s

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Holy big glob of uncommented source code, Batman!  You have "a problem"?  Can you tell us any more about "what's wrong"?  Have you tried debugging yet?  Which debugger are you using?  Gdb?  MSVS? "Something else"?

Comment: sorry:( my problem is that my code works fine if a remove the serialization and de-serialization of the text file. when I had it to the code I get a bad de-serializated strcuture. I will had some more comments. Thanks